# Chart.js, dashed line, full width chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is it possible to make dashed line on Chart.js line chart? And make the chart full width? See attached mockup.

[image]

**This is my current code (Just simple example):**

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("main-line-chart").getContext("2d");
    var line = ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);

    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(40,175,250,.25)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(40,175,250,0)');

    var data = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                pointDot : false,
                fillColor: gradient,
                strokeColor: "#28AFFA",
                pointColor: "#19283F",
                pointStrokeColor: "#28AFFA",
                pointHighlightFill: "#19283F",
                pointHighlightStroke: "#28AFFA",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, null, null]
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.39)",
                pointColor: "#19283F",
                pointStrokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.39)",
                pointHighlightFill: "#19283F",
                pointHighlightStroke: "#28AFFA",
                data: [null, null, null, null, 56, 27, 90]
            }
        ]
    };

    var options = {};

    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
    console.log(myLineChart);
```

Comment: Can you add all of your code please.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Chart.js has evolved since this question was posted but even with the current version 2.9.4, the solution looks almost the same as the originally posted code.

The main changes are the following:

- Instead of using `new Chart(ctx).Line(...)`, we should now use `type: 'line'` as shown [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#example-usage).
- Quite some [`dataset` properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) have different names.
- Use the option [`borderDash`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling) to draw the dashed line of the second dataset.

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("main-line-chart").getContext("2d");
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(40,175,250,.25)');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(40,175,250,0)');

var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      backgroundColor: gradient,
      borderColor: "#28AFFA",
      pointColor: "#19283F",
      pointHighlightColor: "#28AFFA",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, null, null]
    },
    {
      label: "My Second dataset",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "rgba(100, 100, 100,.39)",
      pointColor: "#19283F",
      pointHighlightColor: "#28AFFA",
      data: [null, null, null, null, 56, 27, 90],
      borderDash: [10, 5]
    }
  ]
};

var options = {};
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="main-line-chart" height="100"></canvas>
```